# How to access database server on my desktop from my laptop?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, sql-server

I have a desktop PC, a laptop and a Netgear Wireless Router.

The Netgear Wireless Router has a secured Wireless Network Connection setup already. Its SSID is NETGEAR44.

The desktop PC's name is **Srh-PC**. Its operating system is Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 64-bit. It has Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 database server installed. It is connected to NETGEAR44 as wireless for internet.

The laptop's name is **Srh-HP**. Its operating system is Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 64-bit. It has Microsoft SQL Server client tools installed. It is connected to NETGEAR44 as wireless for internet.

On my laptop I want to open SQL Server Management Studio and then connect to database server of my desktop PC. How can I do that? I am not strong in networking so any tutorial pointer will help.

Comment: SQLServer does not automatically allow remote connections.  These instructions shoudl work for SQLServer 2008R2: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/914277/how-to-configure-sql-server-2005-to-allow-remote-connections

Provided your name resolution is working, you should be able to connect. if you cannot ping the desktop from the laptop, check your AP to make sure you don't have wifi client isolation enabled. that would block your wireless devices from connecting to each other.

Comment: what is AP? sorry I am very illiterate on networking.

Comment: Solve your pinging problems first per your comments.  That is a pretty low level problem.  This question should not even exist if you cannot ping.  That is like saying "I cannot connect to the internet; how do I do so with my network cable unplugged."

Comment: your AP is the netgear wireless device (Router or Access Point) you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per some notes I have saved from a while back on a server with applicable specs, I figured why note throw in an answer and make into some helpful steps to simplify this task.

### Run All Commands on the SQL Server instance OS

**Important:** *Be sure to run all elevated as administrator from command prompt.*

**Find/Confirm Listening TCP Port for the SQL Server Instance**

```
USE [master]
EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on', 'any', NULL, NULL, N'asc'
--EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on'
```

**Note:** Change `<####>` in below commands to the confirmed port number

---

**From Elevated Command Prompt**

*Allow inbound TCP connections to the confirmed SQL port*

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Name of rule/description inbound/outbound on TCP <####>" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=#### profile=domain
```

---

**Allow Remote Access via SSMS Database Connection**

*Manually test from all subnets in case you need to adjust the network scope of the rules. Ensure the `C:\Program Files\~` path is correct for your environment as well as the profiles and the TCP port number.*

```
netsh firewall add allowedprogram program="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" name="Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Database Engine Access" profile=domain 

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Allow SSMS Database Engine connections inbound on TCP <####>" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=<####> profile=domain
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Configure a Windows Firewall for Database Engine Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043(v=sql.120).aspx)
- [Understanding Firewall Profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/getting-started-wfas-firewall-profiles-ipsec(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: @srn Follow these simple steps and let me know if you find this helpful in getting this corrected for you in your environment. My hope is the answer is concise enough to explain in simple terms and right to the point but let me know if you need further clarification, run into trouble, etc.

Comment: right now I cannot even ping from laptop to desktop and from desktop to laptop so I think your solution cannot be tried until I can at least ping

Comment: @srh Did you ever get this figured out or the network issue resolved to access it from the Wi-Fi router or Access Point? Curious of your status so I thought I'd ask you.'