# Connect to Python Server

Tags: python, cmd.exe, webserver

I have create a python server with the following code on Command Prompt.

```
python -m http.server
```

You can find details for how to create the server on [Mozilla's website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server). Using that server any computer on my network can use the websites on it using the IP Address `192.168.xxx.xxx:8000`. When I attempt to connect to my server with Putty and/or FTP, it returns `unknown host`. How do I make FTP or Putty connect to my server? I have made a server with my Raspberry Pi and I could use SSH on Putty to modify the server.

Comment: Open up a Windows FW rule to allow port 8000 thru since you say you are using cmd.exe then that means you're using Windows. Disable the Windows FW and see if it allow you to connect and if so then you likely need to just create a rule to allow port 8000 inbound. Run `netstat -ano` and confirm that port 8000 is indeed listening too.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to that doesn't work as per my comment suggestion in particular? Please clarify what you have tried or can confirm or clarify about your system specifics as per my comment. I understand what you are trying per your question but I'm not sure what you are talking about doesn't work per my comment suggestions or whatever. Read my comment and clarify what with it you have tried or can confirm or whatever as for what I was trying to get clarification or confirmation from you on what I put in the comment. You are running a Windows python server, correct?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT My bad. How do `create a rule to allow port 8000 inbound`?

Comment: From an elevated command prompt run as administrator you will want to run `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="inbound on TCP <####>" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=<####> profile=all` ensuring the `<####>` characters are replaced with the applicable port so use `8000` in the spot of `<####>` in that command. You run this on the Python server that is listening for the connections or whatever.

Comment: Here's a quick answer I used this in before if you want to see it but let me know whether or not this helps any: https://superuser.com/questions/1280298/how-to-access-database-server-on-my-desktop-from-my-laptop/1280308#1280308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the Python http.server does not support FTP.

While Python does have an [FTP library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html), this is essentially a client library intended to help your scripts communicate with existing FTP servers. Python doesn't have a "built-in" FTP server unfortunately.

Given this, you have a effectively two options: use a third-party library or code a file transfer solution yourself. http.server does support [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) with `python -m http.server --cgi`, so it is at least theoretically possible to use this mechanism for transferring data.

For a simple third-party FTP server library, you may wish to look into [pyftpdlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyftpdlib/) (which has [documentation](http://pyftpdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), including a basic [tutorial](http://pyftpdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) page).

Regarding Putty, if you want to SSH into the PC, Windows doesn't have a native SSH server as far as I am aware. Google can help in this regard but, for home use, [MobaSSH](https://mobassh.mobatek.net/) or [FreeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/) may be passable solutions for you.

---

*It has recently come to my attention that sufficiently updated versions of Windows 10 that have the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (WSL) installed may have some options for native SSH. However, I cannot make any suggestion about whether this would be sufficient for your needs or not.*

---

*Using pyftpdlib*

If you do decide to use pyftpdlib, you can install it with pip:

```
pip install pyftpdlib
```

For a simple commandline server (similar to http.server), you can use the following:

```
python -m pyftpdlib
```

This will create a read-only FTP server with an anonymous account. Note that you can enable writing (uploads) with `-w`, as well as specify other options, including specific interface (if any), port and FTP directory:

```
python -m pyftpdlib -w -i localhost -p 8081 -d "C:\path\to\FTP\anon"
```

A full list of commandline option is available with `python -m pyftpdlib -h`.

*pyftpdlib Script Notes*

If you want to run pyftpdlib from the example tutorial scripts on Windows, you should keep the following in mind:

- Windows directory separators will need escaping (that is, you will need to use `\\` between folders rather than just `\`). This does not apply to servers started via the commandline (above).
- If you get socket errors, this is usually either due to a firewall/permission issue with Windows or a port already being in use. Either way, correct the issue or pick a different port.
- The `perm=` attribute of `authorizer.add_user` is optional but, if omitted, the user defaults to read-only access. To see a list of what all the permissions mean, you should have a look at the [API](http://pyftpdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) documentation.