# Can not find port in netstat for a specific PID in tasklist

Tags: port, sql, pid

I have trouble finding the port for a running SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS):

The command `tasklist` in `CMD` shows `PID = 3376` for `sqlservr.exe`.

It's the same `PID` as in the Properties of this SQL Server (looked up under *SQL Server Configuration Manager (Local) / SQL Server Services / SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS))*. The property `State` is `Running` for this SQL Server.

However, the command `netstat -ano` in `CMD` does not show any port for this `PID`.

I assumed that there would be an automatic allocation of this service (this `PID`) to a port. Is my assumption wrong? If yes, how can I assign a specific service to a port?

Does the service have to be in the list of *SQL Server Network Configuration* as shown [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port)? If yes, how to transfer the running SQL Server to this list?

Comment: Have you enabled TCP/IP in the SQL Server Configuration Manager? I'm reading that it is disabled by default. In the TCP/IP Properties, there should be two fields for Port and Dynamic Ports.

Comment: I googled for sql server port, and google returned that it uses port 1433. I then did netstat -aon | grep "1433" and it listed it, and I checked the PID and it's sqlservr.exe. i'm running smss(sql studio), which uses sql server 2014. Do you see anything on that port?

Comment: @root: I have not found the option to enable TCP/IP for my SQL Server which is currently listed in *SQL Server Services*. [This post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port) demonstrates this process for SQL Servers listed in *SQL Server Network Configuration* only.

Comment: @barlop: No, I unfortunately can't see anything with ``netstat -aon`` or ``netstat -aon | findstr 1433`` which has to do with 1433.

Comment: can you try to create a database?  do you get any errors if you try to reinstall it? / did you get any errors when you tried to install it? You could try installing SMSS it has an SQL Server https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: @stonebe TCP/IP is shown in [the first screenshot in the link you provided](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/media/tcp-ports.png). Is yours set to enabled? If you right click it and go to properties, do you have a port set?

Comment: @root worth noting this is how it probably should look https://i.imgur.com/vqJWYuI.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the PID of the process running you could use the below [netstat](https://ss64.com/nt/netstat.html) command piped over to the [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) command followed by the PID number to display applicable detail including the port number that that process is listening.

- `netstat -ano | findstr "<PID>"`

To resolve this issue it should be as simple as adjusting the [**SQL Server Network Configuration**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager) accordingly or opening up the necessary ports, programs, etc. with the [**Windows Firewall** rules](https://superuser.com/questions/1280298/how-to-access-database-server-on-my-desktop-from-my-laptop/1280308#1280308).

---

### Further Resources

- [netstat](https://ss64.com/nt/netstat.html)
- [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [SQL Server is started but didn't listen on any port](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54767/sql-server-is-started-but-didnt-listen-on-any-port)
- [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager)
- [How to access database server on my desktop from my laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/1280298/how-to-access-database-server-on-my-desktop-from-my-laptop/1280308#1280308)

Comment: The solution was found in the suggested post [SQL Server is started but didn't listen on any port](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54767/sql-server-is-started-but-didnt-listen-on-any-port): TCP/IP was still disabled - it had to be enabled with successive restart of the SQL Server.